# Python. Android. Работа с точкой доступа и подключенными устройствами

Tags: python, android, pydroid

Пытаюсь найти библиотеку для запуска некоторых функций Android через эмулятор Python.

В частности решаю задачу запуска точки доступа с заданными параметрами для обработки MAC адресов подключенных устройств.

На текущий момент есть понимание того, как это реализовать на Java, однако сам язык плохо знаю, поэтому свёл всё к этому вопросу.

Буду очень признателен, если кто-либо отправит ссылки на документацию подобных библиотек (androidhelper необходимый функционал не поддерживает).

Comment: Какой эмулятор? Pydroid? QPython? Pycharm?

Comment: @Глеб предположу, что отличий мало, так как библиотека будет работать через методы ОС, а так Pydroid иди QPython 3l.

Comment: Не скажи. В QPython по-моему, вообще библиотеки устанавливать нельзя, в отличие от Pydroid.

Comment: @Глеб не пишите не по теме или про то, в чём не уверены. Меня не интересует эмулятор - его я могу подстроить под нужды, мне нужна библиотека, а в Qpython можно устанавливать библиотеки.